# Load a new webpage in the background of an existing UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, xcode6, uiwebviewdelegate

I already found an article on stackoverflow about loading urls in the background of the app but that is before the webview has been created.  Here is the link: [Background Loading a url in a uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418815/background-loading-a-url-in-a-uiwebview)

I've also implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` into my program but that doesn't allow anything to load after the initial webpage has loaded.

My webview has already been created and it loads a login page.  The purpose of my webview is to only authenticate the user, so after the user has entered their correct credentials and hit 'Log in', the webview should authenticate the user and then the webview should immediately close and load a view controller all without showing a new webpage on the screen.  So, the only webpage I want the webview to show is the login page but the user should still be able to authenticate themselves.

Right now, my code will move to a view controller after getting an LTPA Token from the website, which means that the user has successfully logged in, but the user's account webpage shows up on the screen for a second or two.  If there is a way to pause the image of the login webpage but have the user's account webpage load in the background, I feel this would be the easiest solution.  Is this possible? Is there a simpler answer?

This is how I'm opening the webpage in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MyFakeWebpage.com"];
self.myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[self.myWebView loadRequest:self.myRequest];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the LTPA token from a query parameter when intercepting `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, you could return `NO` from it to prevent the page from loading further. In fact, even if you're not grabbing the token there you could still find the page you're trying to prevent loading from and block it in that method.

You could also load a request to URL `about:blank` to force flush the contents of the web view.